# react-native-google-places-autocomplete unable to resolve module `path/custom/left-icon`

Tags: react-native

I'm unable to use react native autocomplete npm package and i have been getting this error "react-native-google-places-autocomplete unable to resolve module `path/custom/left-icon` "
I'm using react Native V0.44.0 
what am i doing wrong?

[image: simulator error]

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';

const homePlace = { description: 'Home', geometry: { location: { lat: 48.8152937, lng: 2.4597668 } }};
const workPlace = { description: 'Work', geometry: { location: { lat: 48.8496818, lng: 2.2940881 } }};

const GooglePlacesInput = () => {
  return (
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      placeholder='Search'
      minLength={2} 
      autoFocus={false}
      returnKeyType={'search'}
      listViewDisplayed='auto'    
      fetchDetails={true}
      renderDescription={(row) => row.description} 
      onPress={(data, details = null) => { 
        console.log(data);
        console.log(details);
      }}
      getDefaultValue={() => {
        return ''; 
      }}
      query={{

        key: 'YOUR API KEY',
        language: 'en', 
        types: '(cities)' 
      }}
      styles={{
        description: {
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        predefinedPlacesDescription: {
          color: '#1faadb'
        }
      }}

      currentLocation={true} 
      currentLocationLabel="Current location"
      nearbyPlacesAPI='GooglePlacesSearch' 
      GoogleReverseGeocodingQuery={{

      }}
      GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{

        rankby: 'distance',
        types: 'food'
      }}

      filterReverseGeocodingByTypes={['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3']} 
      predefinedPlaces={[homePlace, workPlace]}

      debounce={200} 
      renderLeftButton={() => <Image source={require('path/custom/left-icon')} />}
      renderRightButton={() => <Text>Custom text after the inputg</Text>}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: could you edit your question to include your file? (GooglePlacesInput.js)

Comment: @Bill, thanks for informing me. I have edited my question to include that

Comment: looks normal to me, maybe try `rm -rf node_modules` in the project root directory, and then run `yarn`, then run `yarn start --reset-cache`? What version of autocomplete are you using btw? (it should say in `package.json` file)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have been able to resolve it

Answer (score 2):

Just take out the line

```
 renderLeftButton={() => <Image source={require('path/custom/left-icon')} />}
```

Or replace it with a text or your own image. You should replace that path with your own text or image or you should take it out completely if you do not need it.

Try this for example:

```
renderLeftButton={() => <Text> Left Button or Left Icon </Text>}
```

Answer (score 0):

for those not using yarn run `npm start -- --reset-cache` if it shows error "moduler cannot listen to port 8081" try killing all the processes listening/using that port. For mac get the process id by running `sudo lson -i :8081` then kill each process `kill -9 pid`.